# angular 6 deploy node.js static path

Tags: node.js, angular

When I set a static path `public` folder and set angular `index` in `public`:

app.js (node.js):

```
//node.js static file path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  //angular index
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

There are some problems with this setup:

(1)I can't put all angular build files in a specific folder(like put in `dist` folder), `index.html` will not be able to take the correct location of the relevant file(like `runtime.js`)

(2)Some files may be stored in the public folder, such as files uploaded by users. angular build will be clear all files in the folder(`public`), so I have to pack it in another folder(ex:dist) and manually copy all the files to the `public` folder. This setting is quite inconvenient, and every time you update it, make sure the old file is cleared.

---

**Update**

app.js (node.js):

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => { 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist', 'index.html')); 
    // or res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

angular.json:

```
"outputPath": "server/public/dist/",
```

angular build

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url /dist/ --base-href /dist/
```

When I link index url:

http://localhost:3000/

angular router will be render /index like `http://localhost:3000/index`,
but `node.js` it's render `http://localhost:3000/dist/index`

Can't the URL hide the folder path `dist`?
Is this the correct way to set up?

Comment: --deploy-url /public/ --base-href /public/ --output-path c:\inetpub\wwwroot\public

Comment: `--output-path c:\inetpub\wwwroot\public`  build public folder? that will be clear public folder.

Comment: @AlbertChen In short you want to make a build to upload on live ? Is it your main aim to do this 
?

Comment: @SachinShah I don't know how to be a better deployment process. I want to know what kind of method is appropriate. When I use the angular + node.js

Comment: @AlbertChen So you need the steps to upload app on live. Am I right ?

Comment: @SachinShah yes.

Answer (score 0):

For run project on live domain. Follow this steps.

Step 1: Make a build with this command. ng build --prod.

Step 2: In Dist/index.html , Update base URL with your domain name.

Step 3: Make ZIP file of dist folder.

Step 4: Copy and paste ZIP folder into you respective server. you can use filezilla for that.

Step 5: Unzip folder.

Step 6: Update dist folder name to your project folder name.

Step 7: Check on browser.

Comment: thank, but I want to know more details about how to set angular and node.js seeting. Like about node.js app.js, router,   static path.., angular router, build..

Comment: @AlbertChen For this points , you have to do some googling and implement by your own. I can't explain this all stuff hear. I can just help you either in code or in any concept. For your point's I suggest you to learn all stuff from any official doc or from turorialspoint.

Comment: ok. I have already looked for relevant tutorial, but these tutorial have not talked about the deployment part, or just a brief explanation.

Comment: @AlbertChen I have already give to deployment part in my answer.